# Insert into table with a foreign key

Tags: sql, postgresql

Using Postgresql

Customer

```
Nmb_id | Order History | Search |
```

Contacts

```
Primary_Key | Nmb_id_fk | Fax | Email |
```

Nmb_id_fk is a foreign key to the Customer primary key Nmb_id.

Trying to insert data into a table with a FK relationship:

SQL:

```
insert into contacts (fax, email, Nmb_id_fk) 
values( '123', 'a@a.com', (select "Nmb_id" from customer where "Nmd_id" = 4));
```

Keep getting error:

> ERROR:  column "Nmb_id_fk" of relation "contacts" does
>   not exist

Comment: You show two tables.  Neither is called `contacts`.  And neither has a column called `Nmd_id`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sorry had to edit it so I don't show production table names. Got sloppy, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Since you know that `Nmd_id = 4` why you need a `SELECT` there? Also I think you need to show some DDL

Answer (score 1):

```
insert into contacts (fax, email, "Nmb_id_fk") 
select '123', 'a@a.com', c."Nmb_id" 
from customer c 
where c."Nmd_id" = 4;
```