# How do I insert data into a table with foreign keys?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, derby

I have two tables:

user: `user_id(PK) | name` 
product: `product_id(PK) | product | user_id(FK)`

It's an one-to-many relationship (one user can have multiple products). I created my tables with following statements:

```
String stmt_user = "create table user (user_id int not null generated by default as identity," 
                   + "name varchar(20), " 
                   + "primary key(user_id))";

String stmt_prod = "create table product (product_id int not null generated by default as identity,"
                   + "product varchar(20), "
                   + "constraint ads_pk primary key(product_id), "
                   + "foreign key(user_id)  references user(user_id) on delete cascade)";
```

What can I do, when I want to insert multiple products into one specific user with the id 2?
Something like this: "insert into product values(product) where user(user_id) = 2".
This is how my table should look like:

```
|---------------------|------------------|---------------|
|      product_id     |     user_id      |    product    |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------|
|          1          |         2        |     bacon     |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------|
|          2          |         2        |     pizza     |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------|
|          3          |         2        |     beans     |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------|
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah finally found my answer from here:
[Insert into table with a foreign key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53242023/insert-into-table-with-a-foreign-key)

I had to update my create product statement:

```
String stmt_prod = "create table product (product_id int not null generated by default as identity,"
                   + "product varchar(20), "
                   + "constraint ads_pk"
                   + "foreign key(user_id) references user(user_id) on delete cascade)";
```

And now my insert product statement looks like this and works well:

```
"insert into product (product, user_id) select product, u.user_id from user u where u.user_id = 2");
```